# python script to build multiple .msbuild files

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, subprocess

I am really new in Python so I apologise for the rookie mistakes :)

I need to write a python script which sets the environment for Visual Studio, then creates a temporary workspace, checks out the latest version from tfs and finally runs multiple .msbuild files under a single directory and saves the output to a log file.

I came up with this script but it is not working:

```
import subprocess
command = "cmd.exe /C dir C:\\"

all_logs = []

def run_cmd(command):
    """run a command and print output"""
    print 'Running: "%s"' % command
    print 'Working dir: %s' % os.getcwd()
    print 'Env params: %s' % os.environ
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    out, err = p.communicate()
    print 'output: %s' % out
    print 'error: %s' % err
    all_logs.append(out)

def set_env_params():
    os.environ['PATH'] = os.environ['PATH'] + r';C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC'

def run_tasks():
    #Get Variables
    #set Env Parameters
    set_env_params()
    #source code checkout
    #script
    run_cmd('tf get C:\Users\username\Documents\TFS /recursive')
    run_cmd('msbuild.exe   C:/Users/username\Documents\TFS\BuildScripts/msbuild/libraries.msbuild')
    run_cmd('msbuild.exe   C:\Users\username\Documents\TFS\BuildScripts/msbuild/pex.msbuild')
    run_cmd('msbuild.exe   C:\Users\username\Documents\TFS\BuildScripts/msbuild/dhsati.msbuild')
    run_cmd('msbuild.exe   C:\Users\username\Documents\TFS\BuildScripts/msbuild/dhbati.msbuild')
    run_cmd('msbuild.exe   C:\Users\username\Documents\TFS\BuildScripts/msbuild/view.msbuild')
    run_cmd('msbuild.exe   C:\Users\username\Documents\TFS\BuildScripts/msbuild/datafeed.msbuild')
    run_cmd('msbuild.exe   C:\Users\username\Documents\TFS\BuildScripts/msbuild/apps.msbuild')
    run_cmd('msbuild.exe   C:\Users\username\Documents\TFS\BuildScripts/msbuild/misc.msbuild')
    run_cmd('msbuild.exe   C:\Users\username\Documents\TFS\BuildScripts/msbuild/sdp.msbuild')
    run_cmd('msbuild.exe   C:\Users\username\Documents\TFS\BuildScripts/msbuild/unittests.msbuild')


def main():
    print '### STARTING TASKS ###'
    run_tasks()
    print '### FINISHED TASKS ###'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #to run if this python script it executed directly
    main()
```

The main issues I have are:
1) setting the env variables gor VS2010 is not enough. In order for the cmd to understand the 'tf' commands I also need to run the **vcvarsall.bat** file.

2) If I add the 'start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"' command, another cmd is opening, with the correct environment but the commands that follow, in the script, cannot be inserted in this new cmd.

I also tried by writing a bat file, that I would run from my script but I had the same issue with the cmd processes.

Questions:

1) is there a way to run all the commands under a single process?

2) what is the best way for me to do this?

Comment: *I also tried by writing a bat file, that I would run from my script but I had the same issue with the cmd* how so? A batch file which first runs vcvars and then uses msbuild should work ok.

Comment: I used 'start', now that I use call it doesnt do it. But still, how can I do this by using only the python script. Is there also a way to pass the 'env setting' that the vcvarsall.bat file does as variables into the python script, and if yes how? Too many questions, I know, I am sorry but I am really trying to understand